# inferring a continuous latent parameter from a discrete observed parameter

Tags: stan

I am interested in models where the observed data is a discretization of a continuous latent parameter.

As a simple example imagine that you have observations `J_i`,

where

```
      J_i = 1 if L_i >= 1

      J_i = -1 if L_i < -1

      J_i = 0 if -1 <= L_i < 1
```

where `L_i = \mu + \epsilon_i`

and we want to infer `\mu`

How would this be implemented in Stan?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `L[i]` is normally distributed with mean `mu` and standard deviation `epsilon[i]`, one approach is to consider that `J[i]` is drawn from a categorical distribution of 3 categories (i.e., -1, 0, 1), with parameters `theta[i]` (each of length 3), where each `theta[i][j]` is the area under the normal probability distribution with parameters `(mu, epsilon[i])`, at the corresponding interval. An example can be seen below.

[image: Example distributions for L and J.]

So, we can include `theta` as a parameter matrix in a `transformed parameters` block, without needing to specify `L` at all in the Stan model. An example implementation is the following. Note that the categories are here considered as `1, 2, 3` instead of `-1, 0, 1`, for convenience in using the `categorical` function.

model.stan:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;   // number of samples
  int J[N];         // observed values
}

parameters {
  real mu;                    // mean value to infer
  real<lower=0> epsilon[N];   // standard deviations
}

transformed parameters {
  matrix[N, 3] theta;         // parameters of categorical distributions
  for (i in 1:N) {
    theta[i, 1] = Phi((-1 - mu) / epsilon[i]);      // Area from -Inf to -1
    theta[i, 3] = 1 - Phi((1 - mu) / epsilon[i]);   // Area from 1 to Inf
    theta[i, 2] = 1 - theta[i, 1] - theta[i, 3];    // The rest of the area
  }
}

model {
  mu ~ normal(0, 10);     // prior for mu
  for (i in 1:N) {
    epsilon[i] ~ lognormal(0, 1);     // prior for epsilon[i]
    J[i] ~ categorical(to_vector(theta[i]));
  }
}
```

An example usage in R is the following.

main.R:

```
library(rstan)

set.seed(100)

# simulated data
N <- 20
mu <- -1.2      # This is the value we want to estimate
epsilon <- runif(N, 0.5, 2)
L <- rnorm(N, mu, epsilon)
J <- ifelse(L < -1, 1, ifelse(L >= 1, 3, 2))

mdl <- stan("model.stan", data = list(N = N, J = J))

samples <- extract(mdl, "mu")
mu_estimate <- list(mean = mean(samples$mu), sd = sd(samples$mu))
print(mu_estimate)

# $mean
# [1] -1.177485
# 
# $sd
# [1] 0.2540879
```